# How to generate dynamic urls in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I am have a xyz method in one controller. Now I have a url 'buy-m-get-n' which will call xyz action.

`get "/buy-m-get-n" => "store#xyz"`

Now I want to call the same action for different values of m and n. eg: 'buy-2-get-3', 'buy-4-get-5'.
m ,n <= 10

I tried this in routes.rb,

```
[1..10].each do |x|
  [1..10].each do |y|
    get "/buy-#{x}-get-#{y}" => "store#xyz"
  end
end
```

But it gives me new url as,

```
/buy-1..10-get-1..10-free
```

Answer (score 2):

The way you are doing is not standard way.

Why do you not try like this:-

```
get "/buy/:m/get/:n" => "store#xyz", as: :buy_get
```

in this way you can use this url for different value for m and n
for example: -

```
buy_get_path(m: 1, n: 2) #this will generate url like - /buy/:1/get/:2
buy_get_path(m: 3, n: 4) #this will generate url like - /buy/:3/get/:4
```

## as per your requirement: -

```
get 'buy-:m-get-:n', to: 'articles#buy_get', as: :buy_get
```

and you can use it as: -

```
buy_get_path(m: 1, n: 2) # this will generate url like: - buy-1-get-2
```

Comment: It works but I want /buy-1-get-2-free instead of /buy/2/get/3/free

Comment: @shubhammishra hi you can do this also. i m modifying the answer. please check it.

Comment: @shubhammishra  in routes `get 'buy-:m-get-:n', to: 'articles#buy_get', as: :buy_get` use this. and use in view layer `buy_get_path(m: 1, n: 2)`

Comment: Thank you @gabbar

Comment: @shubhammishra i would suggest you to do like this as this is more dynamic instead of hard-coded routes. tomorrow you may need more routes then you can go each time in routes do customise your loop for this routes.   feel free to accept/upvote answer if it helped you.

Comment: yes, you are right, making it dynamic will help in future

Answer (score 1):

If `n` will be always fixed to 1 to 10, remove the brackets. `[1..10`] is an array of `Range`, `1..10` is the `Range`.

```
1..10.each do |x|
  1..10.each do |y|
    get "/buy-#{x}-get-#{y}" => "store#xyz"
  end
end
```

[`Range` documentation.](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Range.html)